# Is this the right way to use custom exception

Tags: c#, exception

This will be the last time i ask a question about this :).

I have for a couple off hours now tried to get my head around custom exception handling, how and when to use it. I have asked here two times before about this, and i am really sorry for asking so many times but you people here always so good to explain and help!

I think i now know... just want your thougts about it.

I know there is better ways of solving this but the main purpose of this for me to understand the custom exception and throw statment.

This i my custom exception class:

```
[Serializable]
    class CustomException : Exception
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Just create the exception
        /// </summary>
        public CustomException()
        : base() {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Create the exception with description
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="message">Exception description</param>
        public CustomException(String message)
        : base(message) {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Create the exception with description and inner cause
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="message">Exception description</param>
        /// <param name="innerException">Exception inner cause</param>
        public CustomException(String message, Exception ex)
        : base(message, ex) {
        }
    }
```

This is may class where i use it:

```
public static int ParseParse(string inInt)
        {
            int input;
            if (!int.TryParse(inInt, out input))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Only use numbes!");
                return -1;
            }
            else if (input <= 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    throw new CustomException("The price must be greater than zero");
                }
                catch (CustomException ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "No negativ numbers or zero");
                    return -1;
                }

            }
            else
            {
                return input;
            }

        }
```

And this is where i call this class above:

```
if (HelpClass.ParseInput(txtPrice.Text) <= 0)
                {
                    ok = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    newGame.Price = HelpClass.ParseInput(txtPrice.Text);
                    _mGames.AddNewGame(newGame);
                }
```

Comment: Why don't you return simply `-1` instead of throwing and catching an exception.

Comment: There is no point to catch the exception that must always be thrown. (The entire catch in 'ParseParse' and corresponding and MessageBox.show should probably be removed from the method; make sure to post *accurate* code.)

Comment: I think duplicate [don't use exceptions for flow control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729379/why-not-use-exceptions-as-regular-flow-of-control) should cover your case. Side note: Have you noticed insane amount (-4) of negative votes on answer you've accepted?

Comment: I did not see that Alexei.. must have accepted wrong awnser.. i have changed that now..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to throw an exception here, then catching it in the same method makes no sense - just get rid of exception handling all together. You should throw the exception in `ParseParse` and catch it somewhere else in the call hierarchy. Remember that exceptions are propagated up the call stack, so you can even catch an exception in the `Main` method if it hasn't been already handled, no matter where the exception was thrown.

```
else if (input <= 0)
{
    throw new CustomException("The price must be greater than zero");
}
```

Now you can use the method like this:

```
try
{
    if (HelpClass.ParseInput(txtPrice.Text) <= 0) // No more code in the try block will be executed if ParseParse throws an exception
    {
        ok = false;
    }
    else
    {
        newGame.Price = HelpClass.ParseInput(txtPrice.Text);
        _mGames.AddNewGame(newGame);
    }
}
catch (CustomException ex)
{
    // exception handling logic goes here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for a serious awnser that explaind good!